# Having root directory abstracted?

Tags: linux-kernel

Am trying to find a way of concealing my root directory and having my applications running from a different directory all together.
Would really appreciate ideas and opinions in this exploration.

Comment: Like with Chroot? https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)? Could you otherwise give some examples of what you want?